# Truncation of a Cayley graph

Tags: graph-theory, automorphism-group, algebraic-graph-theory, cayley-graphs

How do you show that the Cayley graph Cay ($A_4$, {(0,1,2), (0,2,1), (0, 1), (2, 3)}) is the truncation of $K_4$? What's its automorphism group? Remark: $A_4$ is the alternating group and $K_4$ is the complete graph on 4 elements.
Thanks for you reply.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Look at the picture [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:A4_Cayley_graph.png) and the first question will be clear to you.